# IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3 Scala Worksheet not working

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

New to scala and I am doing this course https://www.coursera.org/learn/effective-scala
I am following the installation instructions, have installed Scala, latest JDK and IntelliJ on my PC. I installed the Scala plugin as well.
I have downloaded the empty project from the course and imported it into Intellij and have opened the worksheet which has just some basic lines inside. When i try to evaluate the project, the right side shows nothing, but the green tick it had before turns to an exclamation mark, so something must be wrong...
I can't click the exclamation mark or hover over it, no errors to be seen anywhere apart from the visual, see the screenshot below:
[image]

As you can see top right there is a red circle with an exclamation mark in it.
Note that when I run the Scala REPL, that works fine, as you can see below with the latest version [image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue while trying something out in Intellij IDEA `2022.2.4` (Ultimate Edition) on macOS Ventura.

Do the following to fix it:

1. Click the little spanner icon (*Show worksheet settings*).
2. On the first tab in the dialogue box (*Settings for <sheet name>*),

   => `Check` **Interactive Mode**

   => Change **Run Type** to `Plain`

   => Click `OK`.
3. [Optional] If you don't see the evaluation happening after those settings, click the *Play* button (*Evaluate worksheet*) on the worksheet. This should only be for the first time (automatic evaluation in subsequent changes to the worksheet content.

---

See the image below for the settings described above:

[image]